# What is the correct typeof a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, function, object, typeof

Most people know that all functions in JavaScript are actually objects, but why is it that `typeof function() {}` returns `function` instead of `object`? By this logic, why does `typeof []` not return `array`?

Is this just a 'standard' that is followed or is there a valid reason?

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3

Comment: Because `typeof` is weird and inconsistent (sadly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that's what the [spec](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.3) says.

`typeof` returns primitive types only; all regular objects are reported as `"object"`.

Comment: Except for functions which I wouldn't call a primitive type.

Comment: and `null`, which *is* a primitive but `typeof` returns `"object"`.

Comment: and host objects, which might return anything (but not *undefined*, *boolean*, *number*, or *string*).